# Mysql advanced SELECT, or multiple SELECTS? Movies keywords

Tags: mysql, database, join, keyword, optimization

I have a mysql database with movies as follows:

> MOVIES(id,title)
>
> KEYWORDS_TABLE(id,key_id) [id is
> referenced to movies.id, key_id is
> refernced to keywords.id]
>
> KEYWORDS(id,keyword) //this doesn't matter on my example..

Basically i have movies with their titles and plot keywords for each one, i want to select all movies that have the same keywords with with a given movie id.

I tried something like:

> SELECT key_id FROM keywords_table
> WHERE id=9
>
> doing that in php and storing all the
> IDs in an array $key_id.. then i build
> another select that looks like:
>
> SELECT movies.title FROM
> movies,keywords_table WHERE
> keywords_table.key_id=$key_id[1] OR
> keywords_table.key_id=$key_id[2] OR
> ......... OR
> keywords_table.key_id=$key_id[n]

This kinda works but it takes too much time as we talk about a database with thousands of thousands of records.

So, any suggestions?? thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One thing you could improve... Instead of writing `x = a OR x = b OR x = c` you can shorten it to just this: `x IN (a, b, c)`.

```
SELECT movies.title
FROM movies,keywords_table
WHERE keywords_table.key_id IN ($key_id[1], $key_id[2], ..., $key_id[n])
```

Note also that you are missing a join condition in your query. You are currently doing a CROSS JOIN, also known as a cartesian product. I think you want this:

```
SELECT movies.title
FROM movies
JOIN keywords_table
ON movies.id = keywords_table.id
WHERE keywords_table.key_id IN ($key_id[1], $key_id[2], ..., $key_id[n])
```

This query can return the same movie more than once so you might want to add `DISTINCT` to remove the duplicates. Also you can do the whole thing in one query instead of two as a further optimization:

```
SELECT DISTINCT M.title
FROM keywords_table K1
JOIN keywords_table K2
ON K2.key_id = K1.key_id
JOIN movies M
ON K2.id = M.id
WHERE K1.id = 4
```

Regarding the performance, make sure that you have the primary key set to `(id)` on `movies` and to `(key_id, id)` on `keywords_table`.

Comment: Joining is probably more efficient... and won't fail after 2100 records as in another question.

Comment: I didn't mean that... both operations could be substituted by a single query with multiple `JOIN` s

Comment: And this is reason why using the implicit joining is bad. Here was an unnoticed cross join. It is a poor practice to use implicit joins. Glad to see you use the explicit syntax instead of just fixing the implicit syntax to remove the cross join.

Comment: Deleted my previous comment after you fixed it. That final query sure looks nice. I'm going to test it right now.

Comment: Yap it worked for me too, but it takes too much time (for my database), it seems building up the list with related movies on "real time" is not a good choice, i may try building some predefined lists with relations between movies or something.. what do you suggest guys??

Comment: Sorry - had to delete comment saying that it worked. Supyxy, can you run an `EXPLAIN` on that query and give us the amount of `rows` it's selecting? It should show four steps. phpMyAdmin will do this easily.

Comment: Table K1 - 144 rows
Table K2 - 21 rows
Table M - 1 row
Well, i don't think it's a good solution, each movie has at least 50 keywords, there are about 1 milion overall, and the script must check for every keyword of a given movie if there are other movies with the same keyword.. it took about 1 minute lol:)

Comment: @Supyxy: Have you created the primary keys as I suggested? Can you post your table definitions? This query shouldn't be that slow.

Comment: Movies - id[int(8), Primary Key, auto_increment, Unique],  Keyword_table - id[int(8), Index, Foreign Key movies.id] / key_id[int(8), Index, Foreign Key keywords.id]  .. should i remove the indexes and add Primary keys on them?

Comment: Yep i changed them to primary keys, it's quite better but it takes about 5 seconds, which is way too long. Will look for other methods, maybe i should redesign the tables and build some predefined lists with related movies like creating a table for each keyword and listing there all movies..

Would it be fine if i open a new thread about optimizing my DB?

Answer (score 0):

Try using the 'in' keyword instead of building a large number of boolean operations.

```
SELECT movies.title FROM movies WHERE keyword_table.key_id IN ($key_id[1],..,$key_id[n])
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a subselect:

```
SELECT DISTINCT m.title
FROM movies m
WHERE id IN (
    SELECT id
    FROM keywords_table
    WHERE id = 9);
```

Comment: I think you are missing a join.