# How to get oracle join in SQL server?

Tags: sql, sql-server

While migrating website to sql server from oracle server . We have stuck up with the following type queries.We have several tables and joins like this .For example like below

```
Select * 
from Job_master J,
     Batch_master B 
where J.BUS_DATE (+)= B.BUS_DATE
```

.Do we have any solution other than converting all queries to use right outer join or left outer join .?

Comment: There is no way to do this in SQL Server http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8251323/oracle-style-joins-in-sql-server

Comment: You shouldn't have used `(+)` in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

you can use this command which is similer to the above

```
Select * from Job_master J right outer join Batch_master B
 on J.BUS_DATE = B.BUS_DATE
```

Comment: While this works because the query is rewritten, the OP is asking if they can run Oracle join syntax on SQL Server which you cannot.

Answer (score 1):

For right outer join

```
    Select * 
    from Job_master J
        Right Outer Join
         Batch_master B 
         On J.BUS_DATE = B.BUS_DATE
```

for left outer join

```
    Select * 
    from Job_master J
        Left Outer Join
         Batch_master B 
         On J.BUS_DATE = B.BUS_DATE
```

For Inner jOin

```
    Select * 
    from Job_master J
        Inner Join
         Batch_master B 
         On J.BUS_DATE = B.BUS_DATE
```

Answer (score 0):

You can write non-ANSI outer joins ONLY if you are using compatibility level 80 (SQL 2000).
The same syntax in SQL Server 2008R2 would be:

```
select *
from dbo.Address ad, dbo.Street st
where st.Id *= ad.StreetId
```

(transform the (+) into a *)

If you would run this in a database without the compatibility level 80, then you'd get a nice error message that this is not possible:

> Msg 4147, Level 15, State 1, Line 4 The query uses non-ANSI outer join
>   operators ("*=" or "=*").  To run this query without modification,
>   please set the compatibility level for current database to 80, using
>   the SET COMPATIBILITY_LEVEL option of ALTER DATABASE.  It is strongly
>   recommended to rewrite the query using ANSI outer join operators (LEFT
>   OUTER JOIN, RIGHT OUTER JOIN).  In the future versions of SQL Server,
>   non-ANSI join operators will not be supported even in
>   backward-compatibility modes.

But while it may be doable, it's not at all recommended to use it (it's ambiguous and deprecated). Please read the other question mentioned in the comments, Jeremiah has a good answer on it.